# Free surface boundary condition

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, boundary-conditions

I am trying to verify the following identity. Considering the tensile component in the tangential direction on the free surface at a fluid-air interface
$$
\vec{s} \ \tau \ \vec{n} = 0
$$
where $\vec{s}$ is a tangent vector to the surface and $\vec{n}$ is the normal vector to the free surface, while $\tau$ is the stress.

Why is the above expression true? When I calculate the expression using
$$
\vec{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+h_x^2}} \left(-h_x,1\right)\,, \\
\vec{s} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+h_x^2}} \left(1,h_x \right)
$$
where $h_x = \partial h/\partial x$ and $h = h(x,t)$ indicates the depth from the bottom of the container to the free surface then
$$
\vec{s} \ \tau \ \vec{n} = \mu \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)\,,
$$
which is obviously not zero.

Comment: Welcome to physics stackexchange. Please edit your question to make clear what you are interested in. Actually ask a question. ;)

Comment: Also, I think the two "tangent vectors" might possibly a typo... Is n a normal vector? Or is s a tangent vector that is not tangent to the free surface? Otherwise there's no point in using two different symbols.

Comment: @kricheli Sorry, I already corrected what you told me. Thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer.** The condition you're looking for comes from the boundary condition (jump condition) at the interface between water and air, neglecting the viscosity of air.

**Boundary/jump condition at interface.**
Stress boundary condition at a surface comes from jump condition on stress, derived from the integral equilibrium of an elementary fluid volume, "with the thickness much smaller than the dimensions in the local plane of the surface", and reads

$\mathbf{t_n}_1 = \mathbf{t_n}_2$.

For a pair of fluids for which the stress vector can be written as the sum of pressure and viscosity contributions

$-p_1 \mathbf{\hat{n}} + \mathbf{s_n}_1 = 
-p_2 \mathbf{\hat{n}} +\mathbf{s_n}_2$,

being the viscosity contribution given as $\mathbf{s}_n = \mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \mathbb{S}$, where the viscous stress tensor can be written as $\mathbb{S} = 2 \mu \mathbb{D} + \lambda (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}) \mathbb{I}$ for a Newtonian fluid.

**Boundary/jump condition at interface: components.**
Now, we can write the jump condition separating the contributions in normal direction $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$ and tangential direction $\mathbf{\hat{t}}$, namely

$\mathbf{\hat{n}}: \qquad -p_1 + \mathbf{s_n}_1 \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} = 
-p_2  +  \mathbf{s_n}_2  \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} $
$\mathbf{\hat{t}}: \qquad \mathbf{s_n}_1 \cdot \mathbf{\hat{t}} = 
\mathbf{s_n}_2  \cdot \mathbf{\hat{t}} $

and these can be re-written as

$\mathbf{\hat{n}}: \qquad$$ [ -p_1 \mathbf{\hat{n}} + \mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot (2 \mu_1 \mathbb{D}_1 + \lambda_1 (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}_1) \mathbb{I} ) ] \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} = [ -p_2 \mathbf{\hat{n}} + \mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot (2 \mu_2 \mathbb{D}_2 + \lambda_2 (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}_2) \mathbb{I} ) ] \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}}$

$\qquad \qquad\rightarrow \quad  -p_1 + 2 \mu_1 \mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot  \mathbb{D}_1 \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} + \lambda_1 (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}_1)  =-p_2 + 2 \mu_2 \mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot  \mathbb{D}_2 \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} + \lambda_2 (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}_2)$

$\mathbf{\hat{t}}: \qquad$$ \mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot (2 \mu_1 \mathbb{D}_1 + \lambda_1 (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}_1) \mathbb{I} ) \cdot \mathbf{\hat{t}} = \mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot (2 \mu_2 \mathbb{D}_2 + \lambda_2 (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}_2) \mathbb{I} ) \cdot \mathbf{\hat{t}}$

$\qquad \qquad\rightarrow \quad  2 \mu_1\mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot  \mathbb{D}_1 \cdot \mathbf{\hat{t}} = 2 \mu_2\mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot  \mathbb{D}_2 \cdot \mathbf{\hat{t}}$.

**Boundary/jump condition at interface, in the limit of vanishing viscoisity of air.**
Now, using the mapping 1:water, 2:air, and neglecting the viscosity of air $\mu_2 \ll \mu_1 \rightarrow \mu_2 = 0$, and neglecting volume viscosity of both fluids $\lambda_1 \approx \lambda_2 \approx 0$, we get

$\mathbf{\hat{n}}: \qquad p_1  = p_2$
$\mathbf{\hat{t}}: \qquad \mathbf{s_n}_1 \cdot \mathbf{\hat{t}} = 0 \qquad \rightarrow \qquad  2 \mu_1\mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot  \mathbb{D}_1 \cdot \mathbf{\hat{t}} = 0 $

The last condition, if the interface is flat and we can use a set of Cartesian coordinates ($x$, $y$ in the plane of the surface, $z$ normal to it), reads

$x: \mu_1 \left[ \dfrac{\partial u_{x,1}}{\partial z} + \dfrac{\partial u_{z,1}}{\partial x}  \right] = 0$
$y: \mu_1 \left[ \dfrac{\partial u_{y,1}}{\partial z} + \dfrac{\partial u_{z,1}}{\partial y}  \right] = 0$

Comment: Intermediate answer, with a bit more physical intuition: In air viscous forces are negligible, the only contribution to the stress tensor is thus pressure, which is isotropic. And in consequence the force exerted onto the water surface by the air above it has a vanishing tangential component.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much for clarifying my doubt!!

Comment: you're welcome. If you have any doubts on fluid mechanics, and classical physics you find me here, with many other vaild people. If you need/like "mathematical" answers, I'm here